# Rewrite rule 301 htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Via `.htaccess`, I would like to create an automatic 301 from an old URL to a new url:

An example old url is: http://www.example.com/test.html?s=2&ss=3

I would like that to be automatically redirected to: http://www.example.com/test.html

Comment: Try not to use external links only for strict cases, because of security reasons. You can upload png figures with your question or better include the code when available. You will have more chances of getting an answer!

Comment: Are you only attempting to drop your query parameters?

Comment: yes i just want to drop query parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match this specific URL and query parameters then you can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=2&ss=3^ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=302]
```

If you want to use this query string with any URI then use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=2&ss=3^ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=302]
```

`?` after `%{REQUEST_URI}` is needed to strip off any query string.